# alamofire: POST request with headers

Tags: alamofire

Checking Alamofire call to send header for POST request, response coming as nil. am I missing something?
httpMethod variable contains HTTP service url string

```
func sendPOSTRequest(httpMethod: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]){

        let token = getToken("Token")
        let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(token)",
                       "Content-Type": "application/json"]

        let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, httpMethod, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON
            { response in
                debugPrint(response)
        }
        print(request.response)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The position of the parameters is important. Try this.

```
func sendPOSTRequest(httpMethod: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]){

    let token = getToken("Token")
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(token)",
                   "Content-Type": "application/json"]

    let request = Alamofire.request("http://google.es", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
    print(request.response!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a minor point but in my projects I use the `.authentificate(user: String, password: String)` method.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#authentication